# How to add response id and join object at the same time

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to response 2 values at the same time:

```
  @Column(name = "category_id")
  private int categoryId;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
  private Category category;
```

The first, is just a ID of category and the second one is nested object of this ID.

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "productName": "Product HHYDP",
  "categoryId": 1,
  "unitInStock": 23,
  "unitPrice": 18,
  "category": {
    "id": 1,
    "categoryName": "Beverages",
    "description": "Soft drinks, coffees, teas, beers, and ales",
    "picture": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Mapping in your entity od categoryId is unnecessary, because it is equal to category.id. You can just remove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mark this column as not insertable and not updatable.
Another thing is to implement getter for this property as return value of category id.

```
@Column(name = "category_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@JsonProperty(value="categoryId")
private int categoryId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
private Category category;

public int getCategoryId(){
    return category.getId();
}
```